# Characterization of square matrices.

Tags: linear-algebra

Good evening!
How I can attack this problem? What conditions must be met for the following equalities are satisfied? Let $A$ be a matrix of order $2$x$2$, what must happen for the following is true?

1) $A=A^{-1}$

2) $A^{-1}=A^{t}$

My work:

For 1) I read about involutive matrices, but did not know how to see them so in general.

For 2)  I considered $A=\begin{pmatrix}
a & b \\ 
c &\ d 
\end{pmatrix}$ with $a,b,c,d$ in $\mathbb{R}$ or $\mathbb{C}$, then I found its inverse matrix $A=\begin{pmatrix}
\frac{-d}{bc-ad} & \frac{b}{bc-ad} \\ 
\frac{c}{bc-ad} &\frac{-a}{bc-ad} 
\end{pmatrix}$, and equaled component to component with $A^{t}=\begin{pmatrix}
a & c\\ 
b&d  
\end{pmatrix}$, but when I met each of the equations involved I got to quadratic equations and when I tried to replace their values, came to conclusions that are meaningless. On the other hand, I read that $A$ should be an orthogonal matrix, but neither came to nothing with that. If you could help clarify this issue, I would be very grateful.

Comment: If $A = A^{-1}$, then $A^2 = I$ (the identity matrix). Find $A^2$ (in terms of $a$, $b$, $c$, and $d$), and equate it to $I$. Similarly, for the second part, if $A ^{-1} = A^t$, then $AA^t = I$.

Comment: Thank you very much for your contribution, I just read about your comment and just what you say about $A$ would be an idempotent matrix, and this I have clearer, my biggest question is about the item 2).

Comment: Or a simple approach for the first one is to write $A = A^{-1}$ in terms of $a, \ldots, d$, as $$\begin{pmatrix}a & b\\ c & d\end{pmatrix} = \dfrac{1}{\det A} \begin{pmatrix}-d & b\\ c & -a\end{pmatrix}$$ which tells you that $\det A = \_\_\_?$ and therefore, $a = \_\_\_$?

Comment: Sorry, my mistake, I wanted to refer to that $A$ is an involution matrix.

Comment: For the second one, as I said, use $AA^t = I$. Once you calculate $AA^t$ and equate it to $I$, remember that if $x^2 + y^2 = 1$ for two real numbers $x$ and $y$, then there is some $\theta$ such that $x = \cos \theta$ and $y = \sin \theta$.

Comment: Then $A$ would be given by $A=\begin{pmatrix}
cos(\theta) & sin(\theta) \\ 
-sin(\theta) & cos(\theta) 
\end{pmatrix}$?

Comment: Thank you very much for your attention! Greetings from Venezuela, here are 1.30am. =)

Comment: @DanielaRondón For $AA^t=I$ you forgot $$\begin{pmatrix}\cos \theta &\sin\theta\\ \sin\theta&-\cos\theta\end{pmatrix}$$